# Find three distinct tuples $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find **three distinc tuples** $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$  such that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(2n+\alpha)^2-\alpha n^2+4}{(\beta-1)n^2-8 \gamma n -1}=-1$$

I rewrote the numerator and divided by $n^2$ to get:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{4n^2+4n\alpha+\alpha^2-\alpha n^2 +4}{(\beta-1)n^2-8 \gamma n -1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(4-\alpha)n^2+4n \alpha+\alpha^2+4}{(\beta -1)n^2-8 \gamma n-1} \\ = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(4-\alpha)+\frac{4 \alpha }{n}+\frac{\alpha^2}{n^2}+\frac{4}{n^2}}{(\beta-1)-\frac{8 \gamma}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} \overset{!}{=}-1$$

Since all the terms except $(4-\alpha)$ and $ (\beta-1)$ converge to zero I am left with the equation:

$$\frac{4- \alpha}{\beta-1}=-1 \iff \alpha-3= \beta; \space \space  \alpha, \beta\in \mathbb R$$

In this case $\gamma$ is a free parameter.

So all tuples of the form $$(\alpha, \alpha-3, \lambda) \space ; \space\alpha, \lambda \in \mathbb R$$

satisfy the equation. However, the question explicitly asks me to find three distinct tuples but haven't I just found an infinite amount?  Does the tuple I specified only count as one or something? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: then $4-\alpha=0, \beta-1=0$ and $16/(-8\gamma)=-1$.

Comment: So in that case I can't freely choose $\gamma$ right? I have to choose $ \gamma=2$. So my formula that $\gamma $ is a free parameter isn't correct?

Comment: You also neet do consider the case when $4-\alpha=\beta-1=0$. In this case $\gamma=2$